# Discord.py - Send message as user (not bot)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have for the moment a code that sends a message but only for my own discord server as a bot.

What I would like it's automated sending message to others servers to simulate an activity as if it were my main account

```
def sendMessage(ch, ms):
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():


        channel = client.get_channel(ch)
        await channel.send(ms)

        return ""

    client.run('token')
```

How to make the `sendMessage` code sending a message using my main account?

Comment: You don't. And if you find a way to do that, your account will be swiftly banned by Discord. Allowing a bot to control a non-bot account in any way is against the Discord ToS.

Comment: Thanks Silvio. But you think it's possible to simulate a false activity with Selenium WebDriver for example?

Comment: Anything is possible if you're persistent with Selenium. But, again, I highly recommend against it. This isn't just some fine print in the bottom of the ToS; it's actively enforced and people get permabans for it all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Please, do not do this.

Like Silvio said, if you find a way to send messages as a user through code and you are caught then you might get banned. Don't say we didn't warn you!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Yes, but then it's more clear.